# map function to return 1 boolean value, instead of an array of boolean values

Tags: javascript, arrays, map-function

Say you have an array like this:

```
arrayExample = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

I want to use the map function to iterate through arrayExample and return **true** if all the numbers are less than 8, **false** if they are not. However, when I do this I get an array of trues (like: [true, true, true... etc])

Would I be able to return just 1 value?

Here is my code so far:

```js
var testBoolean = true;
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

testBoolean = array.map(m => { 
    //if a number in the array is >=8, changes the testBoolean to false and return false only
    if(m >= 8) 
    { 
        return false;
    }
    //VS code said I had to have a return here, I believe its because I need to have in case m < 8 (edited after reading a comment)
    return true;
 })
 
 //prints an array [true,true,true,true,true,true,true]
document.write(testBoolean);
```

I'm a bit new to "map" but I believe it does this since it returns a value for every element, just confused on how to make it so it returns 1 **true** or **false**.

Comment: is this supposed to be java or javascript? do understand they are not "one and the same"

Comment: You need that second return statement, in case there m < 8

Comment: @Stultuske javascript, sorry I changed the tag. And that makes sense, thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For something like this `.map()` isn't the right tool. `.map()` is for converting all the elements in your array to new elements (ie: mapping each element to a new transformed value). As a result, `.map()` will always [return an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Return_value) (unless this behaviour is intentionally modified). Instead, you can use [`.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for this, which will tell you if *all* elements in your array match your condition (ie: if your function returns true for every element, then you'll get true as your result, otherwise you'll get false). **The `.every()` method will terminate early as soon as it finds one element which your callback function returns `false` for**, which can help with efficiency:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
const testBoolean = array.every(m => {
  if (m >= 8) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
});
console.log(testBoolean);
```

This can be written more concisely, by just returning the result of `m < 8` (this will either evaluate to `true` or `false`)

```js
const array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
const testBoolean = array.every(m => m < 8);
console.log(testBoolean);
```

Comment: @NickParsons I strongly recommend using`.some()` for better performance since every value doesn't need to be checked.

Comment: @DevMaster `every` also short-circuits like `some`

Comment: @DevMaster As adiga pointed out, `.every()` doesn't (always) check every value, it terminates early just like `.some()` does. As soon as `every()` finds a value which is false, it will stop and return false. `.some()` works in the opposite way, as soon as it finds a value that is `true`, it stops and returns `true`. If it never finds a value which `true` is returned for though, it will need to iterate the entire array

Comment: @DevMaster Thank you for the other option of using .some(). I chose Nick's option since the project I'm working on requires me to check every element. A bit of a different scenario to what I put as my example but the same idea! 

I'll keep the .some() function in mind though. Thanks again to both of you!

Comment: @DevMaster you can easily verify it: You can run `[1,2,3,4,5].every(a => { console.log(a); return a < 3 })` or using the comma operator `[1,2,3,4,5].every(a => (console.log(a), a < 3) )`. It will only log until `3`. Once that doesn't satisfy the condition, it doesn't need to check any further.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest solution is to use `.some()`.

We don't need to check every value. We need to find the first value not less than 8.

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
const testBoolean = !array.some(m => m >= 8)
console.log(testBoolean)
```

Answer (score 1):

From a more general perspective, if you want to return a single value from an Array, `.reduce()` is your friend.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Specifically in your case, you could do

```
array.reduce(function(accumulator, currentVal, i, arr) {
  return accumulator && currentVal < 8;
}, true));
```

So `.reduce()` iterates through your array with an initial value `true` and returns the "previous" value (accumulator) AND whether the current value is less than 8.

You could think of it as

`(true && (a[0] < 8 && (a[1] < 8 ... )))`

The returned value at each iteration becomes the `accumulator` of the next. In this way you could not only do math operations but also change an array of a certain shape (e.g. array of `{w:0, h:0}` objects) to an output of another (e.g. a single number being the sum of all the hypotenuses calculated from each `w` and `h`).